# Special Relativity philosophical implications

Tags: time, physics

If an observer on Andromeda moves forwards and backwards their notion of now here on Earth sways back and forth over hundreds of years

Why don't we constantly oscillate over hundreda of years whenever a spatially separate observer moves?

Does the plane of simultaneity associated with spatially separated observers not lead to multiple versions of each observer per reference frame

For example a plane of simultaneity may crosscut my past therefore a different version of me experiencing my past exists in another reference frame, therefore there's millions of copies of me one per reference frame. Or is this a misunderstanding. Instead relativity does NOT imply multiple versions of each observer, one per reference frame. You are where you are, however I can apply different coordinates to your spatial and temporal position that may contrast with yours but it doesn't mean you are somehow duplicated when you're at these contrasting coordinate in my frame.

When we meet up our coordinates roughly line up so we don't notice this.

So it's not like I'm always interacting with a version of you who has conscious experience that contradicts your own in your frame

Instead it's a matter of labels and coordinates?

THANKS

Comment: The guys [here](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/) try to prove that there is a manifold of simultaneity, but it is – or would be – physically unobservable, which is a major obstacle for them.  As you can see they have limited success proving their points.  Van Flandern's essay on GPS satellite synchronisation is probably the easiest to grasp.

Comment: Does it change anything about how we think of other observers. Or do we just say observers carry their own clocks. Nothing weird happens to them in different frames

Comment: It it is true, nothing weird happens.  Everything exists simultaneously but clocks run at their own rates in their own frames.

Comment: So does it change how we think about the experience of other observers?

Comment: Yes, relative to you, for them time may be flowing faster or slower.  The most extreme situation is if you enter a gravitational singularity, as amusingly described by Stefan Hensel [here](https://qr.ae/pr5wIK).

Comment: But there's not a version of each observer per reference frame?